# Loop and variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a Javascript script which create `option` in my html code, I have a problem when I want to put a loop in my variable. 
The code show me this :

```
<select>
    <option>undefined</option>
</select>
```

I have a table like

```
var event = ["Exercice1","Exercice2","Exercice3"];
```

Firstly, Here my variable :

```
iDiv = $('<select class="form-control">' +
    event.forEach(function (eve) {
        '<option>'+eve+'</option>'
    })
    +'</select>');
iBr = $('</br>');
iDiv.attr('id', 'select' + (currentDivsCount + i));
iDiv.attr('name', 'select' + (currentDivsCount + i));
iDiv.appendTo('table');
iBr.appendTo('table');
```

EDIT :

I created an other array which contains the ID of all Events and I want to put it each

```
var EventId = ["1","2","3"]
```

`<option name="IdEvent">`

I tried it :

```
iDiv = $('<select class="form-control"><option name="'+eventId.join()+'">' 
       + eventlist.join("<option>")+ '</select>');
```

But I have this :

```
<option name="1,2,3,4,5,6">Exercice1</option>
```

Thank you for your helps

Comment: This is the classic closure problem.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for an explanation.

Comment: @PeterVC: This isn't a closure problem. There's no delayed execution of functions created in a loop referencing an overwritten variable.

Comment: By the way, you're appending  a `<br>` and a `<select>` to your table, which isn't a valid placement. They should go in a `<td>` within the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.map().join()` instead of `.forEach()`.

```
iDiv = $('<select class="form-control">' +
        event.map(function (eve) {
           return '<option>'+eve+'</option>'
        }).join("")
        +'</select>');
```

The `.map()` method creates a new Array that contains the values you returned from the function, and then `.join("")`, joins the content of that array as a single string.

---

You could also write it like this, which doesn't require `.map()` at all:

```
iDiv = $('<select class="form-control"><option>' +
        event.join("</option><option>")
        +'</option></select>');
```

---

And since `option` tags aren't required to be closed in order to be valid, you could shorten it a bit more.

```
iDiv = $('<select class="form-control"><option>' + event.join("<option>") + '</select>');
```

Comment: I haven't the undefined error but now I have nothing in my select , it's just : <select></select>

Comment: @user3524214: Did you forget the `return` statement?

Comment: How can I disable the first option then ?

Comment: @user3524214: `iDiv.children().first().prop("disabled", true)`. Or with less jQuery: `iDiv[0].children[0].disabled = true`

Comment: `iDiv = $('<select class="form-control"><option>' + event.join("<option>") + '</select>');` `iDiv[0].children[0].disabled = true` it shows nothing in my select

Comment: Can you help me whit the name of the option please ? I edited the 1st post ! Thank you

Comment: @user3524214: Can't use join to insert the content of two separate arrays. You're back to using `.map()` for this. http://jsfiddle.net/gzrb4xz2/1/ Notice that I use the `i` parameter to the `.map()` callback to fetch the name from the `eventId` array.

Comment: My last question, when I select different option in each select, I want to pass all this selected option with an URL ? How can I do it ? Thanks my friend

Comment: @user3524214: Please research how to accomplish this. If you get stuck on something specific, ask another question. Thanks.